# How to get frame of UIView Nested in UIView's - ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiview

I have an Application in Which there is a lot of `UIView's` Nested together.

I want to find the frame of some `UIView's` with respect to Controller.

I have setup an example:

[image]

I am able to find to frame of White `UIView` w.r.t to `Controller` but how can I find the frame of `RedView` wrt to Controller.

Code to find the Frame of `White View`:

```
      - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
      {
           NSLog(@"--OuterFrame---%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.grayView.frame));
           NSLog(@"--InnerFrame---%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.whiteView.frame));

           NSLog(@"---Frame With resepect to self.view --%@",NSStringFromCGRect([self.grayView convertRect:self.whiteView.frame toView:self.view]));
          }
```

And What if Their is another view inside red View.

Comment: `self.view.convertRect(redView.frame, fromView:self.whiteView)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right general idea. But it's easier if you use the inner view's `bounds`, and use `self.view` to convert:

```
// assumes innerView is a view somewhere underneath self.view
CGRect innerViewRectRelativeToController = 
    [self.view convertRect:innerView.bounds fromView:innerView];
```

This way you only need to specify the view to convert from, and the view to convert to. You don't need to think about what views are in between the two.

Comment: Thanks...It work just great...I try this to find the frame of redView and is working great. One question I want to ask ...is this method independent of nesting..means my view is 10 level deeper in UIView will this work ?

Comment: Yes I am playing with it :)